# MUI Desktop Date picker problem-not showing the picker in UI

Tags: material-ui, datepicker

MUI Desktop Date picker is not showing after deployment in the server.I have used mui/lab/DatePicker but now in MUI documentation now it says

1. import { AdapterDateFns } from '@mui/x-date-pickers/AdapterDateFns';
2. import { LocalizationProvider } from
   '@mui/x-date-pickers/LocalizationProvider';
   I have also used this,but after using this it is showing localeText is undefined.[image]

```
enter code here
import AdapterDateFns from "@mui/lab/AdapterDateFns";
import DatePicker from "@mui/lab/DatePicker";
import LocalizationProvider from "@mui/lab/LocalizationProvider";

 <LocalizationProvider
                                    dateAdapter={AdapterDateFns}
                                  >
                                    <DatePicker
                                      label="জন্ম তারিখ"
                                      name="birthDate"
                                      value={x.birthDate}
                                      disabled={grantorDisabled[i].disableGrantor}

                                      onChange={(e) => handleDateChangeEx(e, i)}
                                      renderInput={(params) => (
                                        <TextField
                                          {...params}
                                          fullWidth
                                          size="small"
                                          style={{ backgroundColor: "#FFF" }}
                                        />
                                      )}
                                    />
                                  </LocalizationProvider>
```

Comment: Did you get answer for this??

Comment: There was a change in the package. So, I moved to the new package and the problem was solved.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
import { AdapterDateFns } from '@mui/x-date-pickers/AdapterDateFns';
import { DateTimePicker, DatePicker, LocalizationProvider } from '@mui/x-date-pickers';
```

import datepickers and adapter from x-date-pickers now, earlier they were in /labs

Comment: The documentation is very confusing

Comment: First, you will need to install [x-date-pickers](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@mui/x-date-pickers) using `npm i @mui/x-date-pickers`, then it will work.